# TI OMAPL137 U-Boot Error: "No ethernet found."

Tags: embedded, ethernet, u-boot, texas-instruments

I am trying to boot a DA830 REV A board that was shipped to me with U-Boot loaded without Linux. I was able to build DaVinci Linux and a root file system, and now I want to load Linux using tftp. I booted the board but am getting an error that "No ethernet was found.". Following is what the board starts up with:

```
SF: Detected W25Q32 with page size 4 KiB, total 4 MiB
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   Read from EEPROM @ 0x50 failed
Board Net Initialization Failed
No ethernet found.
U-Boot >
```

I found one forum that suggested that the ethernet address was not set, and I checked with:

```
U-Boot > env print ethaddr
ethaddr=FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
```

And indeed it is not set. I attempted set it with the following and got an error:

```
U-Boot > setenv ethaddr 01:02:03:04:05:06
Can't overwrite "ethaddr"
```

I also attempted to set it with the following, but it still does not set:

```
U-Boot > env set -f ethaddr 01:02:03:04:05:06
U-Boot > env print ethaddr
ethaddr=FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
```

I don't know what to try next. Maybe my switches aren't configured properly??

Comment: The `ethaddr` (aka the MAC address) looks like erased memory.  U-Boot allows this env var to only be assigned once; but sometimes it is stored in EEPROM.  You could try using writing the MAC address using the `imm` command at address 0x50.  You'll have to `iprobe` to check the I2C devices.  Google for a U-Boot command manual.

Comment: Do you have the source for the Uboot version that's on the board? When I last built Uboot for OMAPL137, I had to add #define CONFIG_CMD_I2C to the include/configs/da830evm.h file to get it to correctly pick up the ethernet MAC from the EEPROM via i2c.